# Change sidemenu list items according to components

Tags: html, typescript, angular7, ionic4

I have a side menu, and 3 components namely -- Dashboard, info and logout.
When I am in Dashboard component, side menu should have logout ion-item.

When I am in Info component, sidemenu should have Dashboard and logout ion-items..

Basically, how to change menu ion-items according to different components

Thanks in advance...

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane>
    <ion-menu side="end">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>{{'app.menu' | translate}}</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages" (click)="myFunction(p)">
            <ion-item [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>         
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public pages: Array<{title: string, url: string, icon: string}>;

  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      icon: 'tablet-portrait'
    },
    {
      title: 'Info',
      url: '/info',
      icon: 'information-circle'
    }

  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    public translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    // set i18n
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Anyone there, to help me with this problem?

Comment: In app.component.ts file, You know the which is current page so based on that you have to push new and remove other pages as per your conditions

Comment: Can u help with some snippets? @Paresh Gami

Comment: Sure. Create sample app in stackbliz and give me url

Comment: Import error, can't find files: Something wrong did